# Allowing implicit construction only from reference to longer-lived value

Tags: c++, c++11

I have implemented a type-erasing reference class that can be constructed from an l-value reference to any type. However, I have run into a bit of a dilemma as to whether or not to allow construction from an r-value.

There are two use cases I have encountered:

1. Constructing the reference as a local variable

   ```
   int i = 42;
   Reference ref1 = i;   // This is allowed.
   Reference ref2 = 42;  // This should cause a compile error.
   ```
2. Constructing the reference as a function parameter

   ```
   void func(Reference ref);

   int i = 42;
   func(i);   // This is allowed.
   func(42);  // This should also be allowed.
   ```

Effectively I want to allow implicit construction of a `Reference` instance from anything with a lifespan greater than the reference, but not from anything with a shorter lifespan.

Is there some way to accomplish this, i.e., to allow `func(42)` but disallow `ref = 42`? I am free to make any necessary changes to `Reference`, but the signature of `func` should remain the same.

Comment: c++ doesn't have lifetime in their type (contrary to rust).

Comment: @Jarod42 True, but I'm hoping there is some other differentiating feature between construction of a function parameter and a local variable that can be exploited here.

Comment: Constructors don't know where they are called from so I do not think you can do this solely in the class interface.  Best I can come up with is what Bathsheba suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want in general cannot be done.

Deleting construct-from `T&&` is reasonable, but `T&&` does not convert to `T&` unless `T` is `const`.  This doesn't permit the function argument case.

You could use a different type for the function argument version than the local variable version.

A more general option is to construct from a universal reference and optionally store a copy if your argument is an rvalue.

```
template<class T>
struct view_type_t {
  std::optional<T> possible_copy;
  T* ptr;
  view_type_t(T& t):ptr(std::addressof(t)) {}
  view_type_t(T&& t):
    possible_copy(std::forward<T>(t)),
    ptr(std::addressof(*possible_copy))
  {}
  view_type_t() = delete;
  // calls view_type_t&& ctor, possibly elided
  view_type_t(view_type_t const& src):
    view_type_t(
      src.possible_copy?
        view_type_t(T(*src.possible_copy)):
        view_type_t(*src.ptr)
    )
  {}
  // this is a bit tricky.  Forwarding ctors doesn't work here,
  // it MIGHT work in C++17 due to guaranteed elision
  view_type_t(view_type_t&& src) {
    if (src.possible_copy) {
      possible_copy.emplace(std::move(*src.possible_copy));
      ptr = std::addressof(*possible_copy);
    } else {
      ptr = src.ptr;
    }
  }
  view_type_t& operator=(view_type_t const& src); // todo
  view_type_t& operator=(view_type_t&& src); // todo
};
```

this emulates reference lifetime extension, where temporary lifetime is extended by the reference.  Such a `Reference` behaves like a naked rvalue reference does in C++.

Now `Reference ref2 = 42;` works, and it is now a reference a local copy of `42`.

I find this technique better than the alternative when making other kinds of view types, like `backwards_range`, which keeps a copy of its source range if it is an rvalue and doesn't if it is an lvalue.

This permits:

```
for( auto&& x : backwards( std::vector<int>{1,2,3} ) )
```

to work.  More generally, if the vector was created as a temporary returned from a function, we can call backwards on it and iterate directly; without creating the local copy, we run into lifetime problems as the lifetime extension of temporaries doesn't commute.

Of course you need a `std::optional` replacement (such as `boost::optional`) outside of C++17 for the above code to work.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is to `delete` a constructor, and use an overloaded function:

```
struct Reference
{
    Reference(int& i){};
    Reference(const int&& i) = delete;
};
```

Since an anonymous temporary cannot bind to a non-`const` reference, `Reference ref2 = 42;` will fail at compile time due to the deleted constructor. Construction from an `int` variable is allowed though.

On the second point, compilation passes if you introduce the overload

```
void func(int ref)
{
    func(Reference(ref));
}
```

Comment: It seems better to delete `Reference(int&&)`, as a const lvalue is also forbidden with your solution.

Comment: Following the example of `std::ref`, it would be even better to delete `Reference(int const &&)` to cover all bases (which is actually my current solution). I fear that avoiding that overload of `func` won't be possible...

Comment: @zennehoy: Cheers. Probably the best I can do with this. I wonder if there's another trick that doesn't require an overloaded function? I was initially thinking of doing something with `friend`ship.